# How to initialize an array of lists with a specific type?

Tags: java, arrays, list, initialization

I have a method that needs to return List<'MyClass>[] and need to set up a local variable to do so, but am having trouble with initialization.

I tried:

```
List<MyClass>[] lists = new List<MyClass>[5];
```

Which gave me an error of "Cannot create a generic array of List"

I tried casting an array of Objects:

```
List<MyClass>[] lists = (List<MyClass>[]) new Object[5];
```

Which gave me a casting error in runtime.

I also tried:

```
List<MyClass>[] lists = (List<MyClass>[]) new List[5];
```

Which resulted in a null pointer exception.

Anyone know what needs to be done to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a list like so (for example ArrayList):

```
List<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

To create an array of this list you do:

```
List<?>[] listArray = new List<?>[]{list};
```

This will put your list in an array. I'm assuming that's what you want and not simply items from the list.

Comment: That does get it to work. Thanks.  Do you know of any way around having to individually create each list before adding it to the array?

Comment: How about using `Arrays.asList(...)` inline to avoid intermediate variables?

Comment: Honestly, no. I don't usually put my lists in an array either.

Comment: There is no way; that's basically deliberate.  All arrays are always initialized to null.